# Symfony 4 _instanceof in Bundle's services.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, service, bundle, symfony4

I have a bundle which has interface `Optimax\HealthCheckBundle\Service\HealthInterface`
I need set tags to all services which implement this interface. I do it with the following directive:

```
_instanceof:
  Optimax\HealthCheckBundle\Service\HealthInterface:
    tags: ['health.service']
```

It works fine when I put this directive into `config/services.yaml`. But if I put this code into my bundle's config (which required via composer) `vendor/optimax/health-check/src/Resources/config/services.yaml` it doesn't work. I don't want copy-paste this directive into `services.yaml` every time when I require this bundle to a new project.

How can I move this directive into `services.yaml` which is in my Bundle's directory or at least into another file in `config/packages` folder of the project?

Comment: Did you load your bundle config in the extension class off your bundle ?

Comment: @Jeroen sure I loaded it

Comment: Interesting detail is that Bundle's `services.yaml` is processed successfully. I added there alias for my Bundle's controller and then inject this controller to another service like with help of it's alias `@health.controller`. And it works perfectly, but `_instanceof` directive still doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try auto tagging all services with this interface in your Bundle extension like this:

```
$container->registerForAutoconfiguration(CustomInterface::class)
     ->addTag('app.custom_tag')
;
```

Taken from the Symfony docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html

Comment: Yes. This helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

To expand on the issue for others.

[`_instanceof`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#auto-configure-with-instanceof) functions identically to the [`_defaults`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html) definition. In that the `_instanceof` definition only applies to the file it is used in.

This prevents third-party bundle definitions from affecting your entire application with definitions like:

```
_defaults: 
    public: true
    autowire: false

_instanceof:
    Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface:
        - method: setLogger
          arguments:
              - '@custom_logger'
        tags:
            - { name: monologer.log, channel: 'custom_channel' }
```

Therefor if the service you are attempting to tag with `_instanceof` is not declared in the same `services.yml` file the tag will not be added.

To tag services that implements an Interface in the entire application, you would need to use the [method provided by @Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51175121/1144627)